# Sftp from Unix to Windows

Tags: sftp

Is anyone aware of a way of sftp'ing from Unix to Windows

Thanks
Damien

Comment: Are you asking if there are any SFTP servers that run on windows or are there any unix clients or both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You setup a server with, for instance [freeSSHd](http://www.freesshd.com/). Then you can use the regular unix client that comes with OpenSSH, which is a bit on the no feature side of the spectrum, or choose among many of the other SFTP supporting unix clients.

Comment: Thanks Vinko. I have installed freeSSHd on my windows machine. Now if i try to do a sftp from my linux box , i get the password prompt . As im trying to file transfer by calling a script , how to get rid of the pass word prompt ?

Comment: learn about using keys on SSH

Comment: Can you help me with this , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14534690/sftp-to-windows-machine-from-linux-using-key-based-authentication

Answer (score 3):

If you just want a Windows client, I'd recommend [WinSCP](http://winscp.net).

Comment: I believe he wants to connect TO windows not FROM it.

Comment: @Zoredache: Yes, that's true. But the overall goal is to transfer files from the Unix box to the Windows. And since it is far easier to get sshd running on a Unix box, an easier alternative would be simply to use a tool like WinSCP on Windows to fetch the files from Unix.

Answer (score 2):

From a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262390/secure-file-transfers#262400) just asked, I saw this mentioned: http://www.freesshd.com. That could allow you to sftp *from* *nix *to* Windows.

PSFTP from the [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) team works ok for grabbing files while *on* Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You can install OpenSSH for windows.
It is a cygwin thing and is a little bit tricky to set up on windows box, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [CompleteFTP](http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/completeftp/overview.html), which is an fast, compact SFTP server for all Windows platforms.

You can use OpenSSH on Unix to SFTP to [CompleteFTP](http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/completeftp/overview.html) running on Windows.

Disclosure: I'm one of the developers of CompleteFTP.

Comment: In our company, we use completeFTP. The first reason is that the user accounts can rely on the Windows Authentication. For us this has 2 advantages :
1- you can refine the NTFS access rights using windows's own security features.. even more precisely than what you can do in unix
2- you can create (S)FTP accounts without touching at the  completeFTP configuration... which was convenient because we already  had scripts to confgure Windows accounts..

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a ready SSH server on windows or you are going to create one? If you need to create a server, then take a look at [SSHBlackbox package of SecureBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbbdev/desc-ssh.php) (our product). It provides powerful components to build a full-scale SSH and SFTP server.

Comment: Please disclose your affiliation in the body of any posts where you make mention of one of your products.  See the guideline listed in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has a large list of [sftp servers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SFTP_servers) many can run on windows.  Some are more difficult to setup and some are non free.  I have used openssh under cygwin and freesshd.

- Cygwin + openssh
- Cygwin + dropbear
- copssh http://www.itefix.no/i2/node/27
- http://www.freesshd.com/
- http://www.coreftp.com/server/
- WS_FTP Server
- Globalscape Secure FTP Server

If you are looking for a GUI sftp client that works on Linux you probably are looking for FileZilla or gftp-gtk.